# AngularJs ng-hide while loading

Tags: angularjs

I have 4 forms of which using angular ng-hide and ng-show to display each when needed. But when the page loads initially it displays all forms while loading and only hide them when loading completes. It really looks crappy while loading. Is there a way i can prevent this from happen?

Comment: [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) was designed for that

Comment: How do i apply it to forms? Having 3 forms

Comment: Usually, you want to apply it to whole app, just for a time, while angular is not here. But you can apply it to what you want - just add class or attribute... *See docs/@asdf_enel_hak's answer below for css rule* Angular remove this stuff when it's loaded and will be applied standard `ngShow/ngHide` features.

Answer (score 1):

[ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) will work for you

example:

in your css:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and in your code:

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-cloak> ... </body>
```

will work, but it will hide whole body. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak:

> The directive can be applied to the  element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

so it's better to apply `ng-cloak` to particular elements:

```
<div ng-cloak> ... </div>
<div ng-cloak> ... </div>
```